# Test to see if characters present in div id

Tags: javascript, jquery

I need some help fixing this code in order to change this JQuery if/else statement to test if a number is present within the div id "demo". Currently the code writes "Empty" when the div has no text inside of it and writes "Full" when it does.

```
<div id="demo"> </div>

   <script type="text/javascript" src="jquery.js"></script>
    <script>
 if( $('#demo').is(':empty') ) { 
    document.write("Empty");
 } else {
     document.write("Full");
 }

    </script>
```

What I want to happen is for the statement to write "Empty" when there is any space or white-space inside, and for it to write "Full" when there is a numerical value inside the div.

Comment: `if(document.getElementById('demo').innerHTML.match(/^\s*$/))` --> I hope that works.

Comment: advice: if you use jquery why don't use jquery at all? Mixed (mutant) jquery with vanilla js is less readable

Comment: If I'm reading this right, wouldn't `var isNotNumber = isNaN(text) || text.indexOf(" ") > -1;` work? This would return true if there's any whitespace or text found, and false if it's numbers only.

Answer (score 0):

I suggest using a regular expression to determine what text is in your div:

```
var text = $('#demo').text();
if( text.match(/\s+/)) { 
   document.write("Empty");
} else if (text.match(/\d+/)) {
    document.write("Full");
}
```

Answer (score 0):

```
if ($('#field > div.field-item:contains("someText")').length > 0) {
    $("#somediv").addClass("thisClass");
}
```

*Edit: Omitted any humor.*